# how to recover a yaml file on ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: ubuntu, data-recovery, restore, extundelete

I've googled and searched for the answer, but non of the software mentioned on the answers can search for yaml file?.
I've changed the config of Foremost duplicating the txt line, changing the txt into yaml format, and tried that, but it seems like it cannot find anything, there's the only yaml folder inside of the output folder so the configs at least reads correctly and in the terminal I get only

```
foremost
Processing: stdin
|
```

for hours. But the file it self is less than a kb I guess or so, and I specified the exact folder where it was... But having no luck with it. What are some other ways? the file is on the VPS contabo server, so I don't have a physical access to the hardware

Thank you

PS also tried undelete but it says

```
extundelete: "/root/massa/massa-client/wallets/" is a directory. You need to use the raw filesystem device (or a copy thereof).
extundelete: Operation not permitted when trying to open filesystem /root/massa/massa-client/wallets/
```

Answer (score 1):

a YAML file is plain text; there's little you can search for but the combination of whitespace and `:`.

However, in all honesty: you deleted that file. It's probably simply gone, *especially* on a VPS (whatever "contabo" is): it's a small file, so chances are its blocks got marked as unused, they became used for something else, or, and that's not unrealistic on a VPS, you're using your file system with a `discard` option, which leads to the bits *physically* becoming unrecoverable the moment you mark a block unused.

furthermore:

> extundelete: "/root/massa/massa-client/wallets/" is a directory. You need to use the raw filesystem device (or a copy thereof).

Exactly what the error message says, you are trying to run `extundelete` on a directory, but it needs to be used on the block device that stores the file system containing that directory.

Comment: thanks, ehm so what should I do get the needed block?

Comment: I tried `extundelete /dev/sda3 --restore-file wallet_AU124mPj9Js3LdPpcUTh2cdBf1BNpSumBqgrSUqjep8aVeStturwy.yaml` and got 
`Block bitmap checksum does not match bitmap when trying to examine filesystem`

Comment: there's no "needed block". As said, in all likelihood, your file is gone for good. Unrecoverable. it is no more. It's ceased to be. It's bereft of its existence, it rests in peace. This is a late file. It's gone and met its maker. This is an ex-file!

Comment: no, not true!!! NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOoooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo.................................................